# View not returning set of array. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, information-retrieval

I'm trying to get array passed from controller to view. For that i have used following syntax:

```
foreach ($sfees as $sfee) {
    $M_fees=M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id);


 };

return view('bill.verify',compact('bfs','grade','M_fees'))->with('student',$student);
```

When i echo $M_fees in controller it is returning 3 values.

In View I have used following syntax to retrieve data:

```
@foreach($M_fees as $M_Fees)
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>{{$M_Fees->fee_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{$M_Fees->amount}}</td>

@endforeach
```

But this is returning only 1 data. Why is that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: dd() your result at controller

Comment: in your controller you are reassigning `$M_fees` every time through the loop to a new value, you aren't adding to it.  not really sure what you are trying to do with all of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `$sfees` and assigning the result to the same variable `$M_fees`.

If you want that to work, you should use: `$M_fees[] = M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id);`. Note the `[]` after `$M_fees`. This way you will get an array, full of results, instead of just the last result of the loop.

Comment: What about view? Will the same syntax work in the view? and while passing the value?

Comment: It is definitely passing all the values now. But I'm having trouble fetching it. I used following but it is responding with errors:undefined property.
{!!$M_Fees->fee_type!!}</td>
     <td>{!!$M_Fees->amount!!}</td>

Comment: You should not do any changes to the view regarding this. You are iterating on the `$M_fees` variable passed from the controller. The problem now is that it is an array with just 1 element. When you fix the code in the controller it will become an array with 1+ elements and your code should work as you expect.

As per your second comment: Use `dd($M_fees);` in the controller and give us the result.

Comment: using dd($M_fees) in controller:
array:3 [▼
  0 => Collection {#273 ▶}
  1 => Collection {#286 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#276 ▶}
]

Comment: So, `M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id);` is returning a collection. Obviously, you are searching by id (primary key), so instead of `whereLoose` you might consider using `M_fees::find('id',$sfee->mfee_id);` or `M_fees::all()->whereLoose('id',$sfee->mfee_id)->first();`. Both of them would return an object instead of collection and `$M_fees` will be a collection of objects - what you need.